# Brightness adjustment doesn't work on Ubuntu 23.04. Device: Lenevo Legion 5

Tags: drivers, 20.04, nvidia, graphics, brightness

I am new to ubuntu. After complete installation, everything works properly expect that i can't adjust brightness. The sound control is working properly. But I can't reduce the brightness and its too bright, maybe max. The ubuntu version i installed is the non LTS one, which is **Ubuntu 23.04** .

*The slide icon only slides but brightness is not adjusted*. Can anyone please tell me how to fix this or is this some bug? I have **Nvidia GTX 1650 Ti** Mobile GPU. Since it didn't work by default, i selected apply changes on "Using NVIDIA driver metapackage from nvidia-driver-525 (proprietary, tested)" from "Additional Drivers" as well and restarted but still doesn't work.

I tried keyboard shortcuts as well but no change in brightness.

**HELP**!!!! The screen is too bright for my eyes and i can't reduce it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
If you want to use only a discrete GPU, configure the discrete GPU in laptop's Bios.
Then reinstall ubuntu from usb, nvidia will be detected and configured correctly. The brightness settings will then be correct as well.

My laptop is a legion 5800h/rtx3060 mobile with nvidia-driver-530(proprietary).

Answer (score 0):

On my HP HP ENVY x360 Convertible 15-eu0xxx, I am add or replace this string in /etc/default/grub file to this.

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="acpi_backlight=native"
```

add or edit this string `acpi_backlight=native`

Then I update this grub configs by command in terminal `update-grub`. After that hotkeys for screen brightness is worked to me.